# Not sure what to change return address to in buffer overflow attack

Tags: c, assembly, stack, buffer, overflow

I am working on a simple buffer overflow attack. The program takes in an array of size 12, which when overflowed obviously overwrites elements on the stack, including the return pointer. The stack looks likes this before I input the elements into the array:

```
0xffffcf80:    0x00000000    0x00000000    0xffffcfa8    0x00209210
0xffffcf90:    0xffffcfd8    0x00209210    0x003514e0    0x080486a4
0xffffcfa0:    0xffffcfb4    0x00350ff4  **0xffffcfd8**  0x08048543
```

I have bolded the one I believe to be the return address.  When I input a hex string, for example: 11 11 11 11 22 22 22 22 33 33 33 33 44 44 44 44 55 55 55 55 and then I have tried another memory location as the last part of the entry in order to point the return address somewhere else.  I always get an illegal instruction error.

I have tried many different memory locations that I get from using the info frames command in gdb, yet they all return the same result.  I think I am just having a difficult time grasping the concept.  I would love any explanation or help, even if it isn't directly related to my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try compiling your program with `-fno-stack-protector` (to disable stack corruption checking) and `-fno-PIE` (to disable randomizing the location of the executable code, since you want to jump at a fixed address).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to overwrite the return address with the address of the code that you want to run.

This code can either be :

- existing code in the binary - in which case you just look up the address for it
- code you provide (by means of [shellcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellcode) in the buffer you overflowed eg.) - in which case you use the address of that shellcode

Note that in all cases, there can be further hoops to jump through, in the form of protection mechanisms (like [buffer overflow protections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection), or [data execution prevention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention), or ...).